# Promoting Data Record Types

Tags: haskell

Let's say we have the following datatype

```
data GsdCommand =  CreateWorkspace { commandId :: CommandId , workspaceId ::WorkspaceId , workspaceName :: Text }
             | RenameWorkspace { commandId :: CommandId , workspaceId ::WorkspaceId , workspaceNewName :: Text }
```

I want to have a function that only take a `CreateWorkspace` :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
handle :: Offset ->
          `CreateWorkspace CommandId WorkspaceId Text  ->
          IO (CommandHandlingResult)
```

That's the way I would do it naturally but I have the following compiler error :

```
Expected a type, but‘ 'CreateWorkspace CommandId WorkspaceId Text’ has kind ‘GsdCommand’
Expected kind ‘CommandId’, but ‘CommandId’ has kind ‘*’
Expected kind ‘WorkspaceId’, but ‘WorkspaceId’ has kind ‘*’
Expected kind ‘Text’, but ‘Text’ has kind ‘*’
```

this is the context :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
module Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.HandleGSDCommand (handleGSDCommand) where

import           Eventuria.Libraries.PersistedStreamEngine.Interface.PersistedItem

import           Eventuria.Libraries.CQRS.Write.CommandConsumption.Definitions
import           Eventuria.Libraries.CQRS.Write.CommandConsumption.CommandHandlingResult


import           Eventuria.GSD.Write.Model.WriteModel
import           Eventuria.GSD.Write.Model.Commands.Command
import           Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.CommandPredicates
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.CreateWorkspace          as CreateWorkspace
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.RenameWorkspace          as RenameWorkspace
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.SetGoal                  as SetGoal
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.RefineGoalDescription    as RefineGoalDescription
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.StartWorkingOnGoal       as StartWorkingOnGoal
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.PauseWorkingOnGoal       as PauseWorkingOnGoal
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.NotifyGoalAccomplishment as NotifyGoalAccomplishment
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.GiveUpOnGoal             as GiveUpOnGoal
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.ActionizeOnGoal          as ActionizeOnGoal
import qualified Eventuria.GSD.Write.CommandConsumer.Handling.Commands.NotifyActionCompleted    as NotifyActionCompleted

type GSDCommandHandler  = Maybe GsdWriteModel ->
                         (Persisted GsdCommand) ->
                         IO (CommandHandlingResult)

handleGSDCommand :: HandleCommand GsdWriteModel
handleGSDCommand writeModelMaybe
               PersistedItem {offset , item = command }
  | (isFirstCommand offset) && (not . isCreateWorkspaceCommand) command = return $ CommandRejected "CreateWorkspace should be the first command"
  | otherwise =   gsdCommandHandler writeModelMaybe PersistedItem {offset , item = (fromCommand command) }

gsdCommandHandler :: GSDCommandHandler
gsdCommandHandler
        writeModelMaybe
        PersistedItem {offset , item = gsdCommand } =
  case (writeModelMaybe, gsdCommand) of
     (Nothing        ,CreateWorkspace          {commandId, workspaceId, workspaceName})                   -> CreateWorkspace.handle          offset            commandId workspaceId workspaceName
     (Just writeModel,RenameWorkspace          {commandId, workspaceId, workspaceNewName})                -> RenameWorkspace.handle          offset writeModel commandId workspaceId workspaceNewName
     (Just writeModel,SetGoal                  {commandId, workspaceId, goalId, goalDescription})         -> SetGoal.handle                  offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId goalDescription
     (Just writeModel,RefineGoalDescription    {commandId, workspaceId, goalId, refinedGoalDescription})  -> RefineGoalDescription.handle    offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId refinedGoalDescription
     (Just writeModel,StartWorkingOnGoal       {commandId, workspaceId, goalId})                          -> StartWorkingOnGoal.handle       offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId
     (Just writeModel,PauseWorkingOnGoal       {commandId, workspaceId, goalId})                          -> PauseWorkingOnGoal.handle       offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId
     (Just writeModel,NotifyGoalAccomplishment {commandId, workspaceId, goalId})                          -> NotifyGoalAccomplishment.handle offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId
     (Just writeModel,GiveUpOnGoal             {commandId, workspaceId, goalId, reason})                  -> GiveUpOnGoal.handle             offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId reason
     (Just writeModel,ActionizeOnGoal          {commandId, workspaceId, goalId, actionId, actionDetails}) -> ActionizeOnGoal.handle          offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId actionId actionDetails
     (Just writeModel,NotifyActionCompleted    {commandId, workspaceId, goalId, actionId})                -> NotifyActionCompleted.handle    offset writeModel commandId workspaceId goalId actionId
     (_            ,_)                                                                                    -> return $ CommandRejected "Scenario not handle"
```

I have to pattern match the fields and pass them to the handles....

Answer (score 2):

`DataKinds` creates new kinds and values, but does not change the type of a value. A `CreateWorkspace` value still has type `GsdCommand`, not type `'CreateWorkspace`.

One option would be to use a phantom type, which wouldn't require the `DataKinds` extension.

```
data CreateWorkspace
data RenameWorkspace

data GsdCommand t = GsdCommand CommandID WorkspaceID Text

handle :: Offset -> GsdCommand CreateWorkspace -> IO CommandHandlingResult
handle o (GsdCommand cmdID wkspID wkspName) = ...
```

Comment: There is something I don't get, I know they are saying  Value Constructor etc... but I don't understand why I couldn't consider for example the sum type Either[Error,String] in 2 types Left[Error,String] or Right[Error,String]... They are a Set of values at the end, aren't they ? It looks like the border they have done between types and values is not cut in the right place... Because, @chepner with your solution I have the impression I'm twisting the language a bit... In my example,  CreateWorkspace and RenameWorkspace are types naturally but at the same time they are GSDCommand...

Comment: I hesitated to use a typeclass GSDCommand instead of a Sum type, but I'm loosing some features like the pattern matching etc... I would love to find some information about this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I've added the solution in the question itself but basically I have to pass on the Class-based way of expressing the problem instead of using the Alternation-based (use of Sum Types...) and trying to play with promoting values...

Comment: Please don't update the question to add an answer. Add it in the answer itself. Also, don't post a screenshot of a book as an answer. Kindly write the answer in your own words and provide the name of the book as a reference.